# ABC, make tolerance threshold $\epsilon$ adaptive

Tags: bayesian, descriptive-statistics, markov-chain-montecarlo, particle-filter, approximate-bayesian-computation

Briefly the **Approximate Bayesian Computation** instead of using the exact likelihood function $L(\theta;x)$ tries to approximate this function with the use of the observed summary statistics $s(x_{obs})$ of the data $x$.

The posterior distribution for the parameter $\theta$ can be defined in the following way

$$p_{\epsilon}(\theta|s(x_{obs}))\propto \pi(\theta) K_{\epsilon}(\rho(s(x_{obs}),s(x_{sim}))$$

$\bullet$ $s(x_{obs})$ are the observed summary statistics,

$\bullet$ $s(x_{sim})$ are the simulated summary statistics, i.e. a sample drawn from $x_{sim}\sim L(\theta;x)$,

$\bullet$ $\rho$ is a distance function between the summary statistics $s(x_{obs})$ and $s(x_{sim})$, it can be for example the Euclidean distance,

$\bullet$ $K_{\epsilon}(\cdot)$ is a probabilistic kernel, usually it is a normal distribution with mean equal to $0$ and variance equal to $\epsilon$. So, the closer the distance $\rho(s(x_{obs}),s(x_{sim}))$ is to $0$ the more weight the kernel $K_{\epsilon}(\cdot)$ gives to the $s(x_{sim})$ (or equivalently to the parameter value $\theta$ that used to simulate the $s(x_{sim})$,

$\bullet$ $\epsilon$ is the tolerance threshold, i.e. it tunes how far we want our simulated data to be from the observed ones.

---

I sketch out the Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) Algorithm that I'm using to sample from the posterior $p_{\epsilon}(\theta|s(x_{obs}))$

For $N$ MCMC iterations do

$1) \ \ \text{Initialize} \ \ \  \theta^{0}$

$2) \ \ \theta^{i} \sim p(\theta^{i}|\theta^{i-1})$

$3) \ \ s(x^{i}_{sim})\sim L(\theta^{i};x)$

$4) \ \ A = \frac{\pi(\theta^{i}) K_{\epsilon}(\rho(s(x_{obs}),s(x^{i}_{sim}))p(\theta^{i-1}|\theta^{i})}{\pi(\theta^{i-1}) K_{\epsilon}(\rho(s(x_{obs}),s(x^{i-1}_{sim}))p(\theta^{i}|\theta^{i-1})}$

$5) \ \ \text{If} \ Unif(0,1) \leq A \ \text{then accept} \ \theta^{i}$

---

I would like to find a way to start from a big value for the tolerance threshold $\epsilon$ and based on how the MCMC performs to decrease it gradually, i.e. $\epsilon_{1}>\epsilon_{2}>...>\epsilon_{T}$.

There is a huge literature for this topic but haven't found something relevant to my case. Two papers that discuss the same problem are,

- [Adaptive Approximate Bayesian Computation
  Tolerance Selection](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bayesian-analysis/advance-publication/Adaptive-Approximate-Bayesian-Computation-Tolerance-Selection/10.1214/20-BA1211.full)

and

- [An adaptive sequential Monte Carlo method for approximate
  Bayesian computation](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-011-9271-y)}.

However, both papers work with particles, where in my case I do not think is appropriate since the simulation of a single $s(x_{sim})$ is really time consuming. Hence, I want something less computationally intensive.

I guess an easy approach (but might be naive) is to decrease the tolerance threshold based on the performance of the acceptance rate or effective sample size (ESS). Ideally, I would like something like the following, when the acceptance rate or ESS are large, then we can decrease the tolerance threshold but I haven't found something in the literature that applies to my case and doesn't work with particles.

---

$\underline{\text{More technical details:}}$

In my problem the parameter $\theta$ is made of

$\bullet$ two parameters $p,\phi \in [0,1]$, with $Beta(1,1)$ prior distributions

$\bullet$ a matrix $N$, with integer elements and dimensions $K\times K$, with a $Poisson$ prior distribution placed on top of the matrix, i.e. $N_{ij}\sim Pois(\lambda_{ij})$

So, in essence (let's assume that $K=4$) if we collapse all the parameters to a vector called $\theta$, we will have

$$\theta = (p,\phi,N_{12},N_{13},N_{14},N_{23},N_{24},N_{34})$$

The data simulation is quite complex, but let as denote is as $L(x;\theta)$, which take a few second to run, but (since ABC is iteration hungry it will be computationally intensive) when I run it within the MCMC where it gets called many time it makes the algorithm computationally intensive.

Comment: Bayesian methods like the Kalman Filter can use particles that are not exact simulations, but still get the right neighborhood.  Particle Flow Filters (Duam-Huang) are pretty good.  The particle doesn't have to be literal.  You can think of the evolution in space as evolution in a parameter space, where the axes are the epsilons you are looking for.  You might be able to get away with only taking a step or two instead of walking the whole distance of the simulation.  There are options.  Could you describe the problem itself in a little more detail?

Comment: @EngrStudent I added some notes. I was thinking on using particles but wasn't sure if it suitable for my case.

Comment: @EngrStudent Because what I'm thinking is that for each parameter I'll need $N$ particles

Comment: ABC is by nature requiring a lot of realisations $s(x_\text{sim})$ so unless $\epsilon$ can be trained using a proxy model that generates $s(x_\text{sim})$'s much faster, the issue sounds rather hopeless.

Comment: @Xi'an Let assume that I find a way to generate $s(x_{sim})$ much faster, how do I train $\epsilon$? Should I include it as a random parameter with a prior on it? Or you refer to something different?

Comment: You can train the tolerance using the pseudo-model until it converges and then revert to the true model, since everything is approximate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm not sure SMC-ABC is the same as MCMC-ABC with a threshold reduction; if I'm not mistaken, it's more similar to rejection-ABC with threshold reduction. So, it might not be exactly what you have in mind. You should check the maybe this paper [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2658655/pdf/rsif20080172.pdf) which explains (one version of) SMC-ABC very nicely and also gives some brief comparison to the original SMC-ABC by prof. Scott Sisson.

Second, I completely agree with Xi'an's comment. MCMC is "slow", and ABC requires many simulations. So, if your bottle neck is the simulation part, not sure how you can continue - reducing $\epsilon$ or not.

As Xi'an suggested, you might be able to use a surrogate to replace the actual simulator. Very simple ones can be Gaussian-Process regressions (check out [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.01321.pdf) paper). Maybe a heteroscedastic GP or a multiple output GP (MOGP). They are however quite simplistic and are limited to a single mode.

There is newer literature in the Machine Learning field - which is called **Simulation Based Inference (SBI)**. They use Neural-Density-Estimators (e.g., Mixture Density Networks, and different SotA Normalizing Flows) and they don't require any thresholds $\epsilon$. I have a series about it on YouTube which you can find [here](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJ71tqAZr195v4B42fOGzHMjHBR0bWw1X). I see it as a natural development to the "Regression Adjustment" papers that improved classical ABC algorithms by uncovering the underlying structure between parameters $\theta$ and data $x$. There is also a great library in Python called "SBI".

My master thesis in Statistics (which is being submitted now) deals with reducing simulator calls in ABC. I tried two methods - one is using a Neural-Density-Estimator as a surrogate for the actual simulator - which is more expressive than GP-surrogates. And another one is using ["Support Points"](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-46/issue-6A/Support-points/10.1214/17-AOS1629.full) which are a class of energy-distance based representative points instead of simple sampling. Both might be helpful to reducing simulator calls, though the NDE surrogate seems to be better at-least for small dimension problems.

Comment: Thank for the useful advises. I change the alg from ABC MCMC to ABC SMC and it runs faster with a good accuracy. Also, another thing, do ppl when they use Bayesian Likelihood free inference, use slightly informative priors?